# upgrade wmplayer to a version of my choice?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-media-player

I have wmplayer 9.00.00.4507 on one computer (comp more)

and wmplayer   9.00.00.3349  on another. (comp less)

I'd like to put wmplayer ...4507 on "comp less".

I don't want to upgrade to wmplayer 10, if I can avoid it. no great reason but I just want to make the small upgrade of wmplayer. from ...3349 to ...4507

Comment: Is there any practical reason why you want to do this? The changes between these versions will be extremely negligible, consisting of maybe a few small bugfixes at best.

Comment: @Connor W No practical reason other than it's potentially useful if there's more than a bug fix or if the bug affects me. I may not want the very latest version. And could a slightly later version contain a newer codec? I did try playing a video that worked on the newer one but the older one said error downloading codec.

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to copy `C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player` over to the other computer.

Comment: when I move the current one into a subdirectory called old, the files reappear.

Comment: also when I try running the copy from  a separate directory on"comp less", it displays the old version, and on "comp more" it displays the new version. So it changes nothing.

Comment: @barlop: You need to replace it, or it will look up the old files. You might want to check what other DLLs that Windows Media Player uses with a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to carry them over too.

Comment: How does that work - how is it looking up the old files when I run the new one? i suppose it is running the new exe but perhaps the old other files since those are in the standard media player directory .  Let's say I replace. So running new or trying to run new, from the media player directory. The old files seem to be in dllcache or something too. How do you know that if I replace it I won't still get the old files copied over automatically from dllcache?

Comment: Either disable [WFP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222193) or replace them in the dllcache to prevent that behavior.